# can you put a value in a dropdown for a php calculator

Tags: php, calculator

im trying to make a php calculator for an F1 tyre wear calculator for a project and im inexperienced with coding can you put a value in a dropdown and cover it with a label.

for example:
drop down has 3 options fast, medium and slow to pick from but in the code they are assigned a value.
fast = 3
medium = 2 slow = 1

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="num1" placeholder="E.G. 1">
<input type="text" name="num2" placeholder="E.G. 1">
<select name="operator">
    <option value="3">fast</option>
    <option value="2">medium</option>
    <option value="1">slow</option>
</select>
<br>
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Calculate</button>
</form>
<p>the answer is %</p>
<?php
if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
    $result1 =$_GET['num1'];
    $result2 =$_GET['num2'];
    $operator =$_GET['operator'];
    switch ($operator){
        case "fast":
            echo $result1 + $result2 + 3;
            break;

        case "medium":
            echo $result1 + $result2 + 2;
            break;

        case "slow":
            echo $result1 + $result2 + 1;
            break;
            
    }
}
```

any help is welcome

Comment: please share the code that you have so that we can help you with the current code

Comment: You’d use `<option value=“1”>slow</option>` to specify a value and “label” for each option in your dropdown.

Comment: ive updated with code

Comment: Your PHP code is not checking for the correct values. `$operator =$_GET['operator'];` will return the *value* of the `<select>`, which would be 1, 2, or 3. However, your `switch ($operator)` is checking for fast, medium, or slow. You need to make sure these match.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a basic HTML funtion than anything.

First you need to make your Select dropdown list using the `<select>` and `<option>` tags like this

```html
<form action="./submit" method="post">
    <select name="speed" required>
      <option selected disabled>Select A Speed</option>
      <option value="1">Slow</option>
      <option value="2">Medium</option>
      <option value="3">Fast</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Then in your PHP code that handles the form submission you can get the value selected from the `$_POST` variable. (Assuming the form method is POST)

Eg.

```php
$speed = $_POST['speed']; // This will be 1,2 or 3 depending on the selected option
```

Comment: ive changed the code to a non working version if you could help in any way

Comment: if you are expecting $_GET you need to aet the form method to be get, or just change $_GET with $_POST. Also change isset($_GET['submit']) to isset($_GET['num1']) as you never pass in a field called submit

Answer (score -1):

In your form tag you must add an action to tell html where to send the information of the form to so i've added `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` which gets the pages current url and basically submits the form to the page you're on and so the information of the form is sent to the current page. After you must add a method as you see below you are telling php to get things from the `$_GET` array but you never actually send any thing to that array so when you put `method="GET"` it sends the form info to that array and from there php can access it.  In your switch statement you have to put the value of the option, you have already defined the value here `<option value = "3">fast</option>` thats going to be what is sent in the `$_GET` array not the text inside the option so you have to put case: "value of the option".

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] // Current page url?>" method="GET">
    <!--Make sure to say which method you are using!-->
    <input type="text" name="num1" placeholder="E.G. 1">
    <input type="text" name="num2" placeholder="E.G. 1">
    <select name="operator">
        <option value="3">fast</option>
        <!--The value will be what is sent not the text inside the option!--
        <option value="2">medium</option>
        <option value="1">slow</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Calculate</button>
    </form>
    <p>the answer is %</p>
    <?php
    if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
        $result1 =$_GET['num1'];
        $result2 =$_GET['num2'];
        $operator =$_GET['operator'];
        switch ($operator){
            case "3":
                echo $result1 + $result2 + 3;
                break;
    
            case "2":
                echo $result1 + $result2 + 2;
                break;
    
            case "1":
                echo $result1 + $result2 + 1;
                break;
                
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).